# Where should I include ITelephony.aidl in a Cordova-based project?

Tags: android, xml, cordova, aidl

I'm currently working in a Cordova-based project which kills/answers a call programatically. I saw some questions about ITelephony.aidl (where to include, etc), but none of the solutions worked in my project.

It's just the .aidl or there's something more? Because I need to use the .silenceRinger(); .endCall(); and .answerringingcall(); methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, managed to add it by including the following in plugin.xml

> feature name="ITelephony"
>
> ```
>  param name="android-package" value="com.android.internal.telephony" /
> ```
>
> /feature

and

> source-file src="src/android/ITelephony.java" target-dir="src/com/android/internal/telephony" /